# combine two rows in a table for a particular condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql which has following columns

```
order
---------------------
id integer 
order_id integer 
status integer
time-stamp timestamp
```

I need to find difference between time-stamps of two rows in the table where order_id is same for both rows and status is 2 for one row  and  status is 4 for another row.

I tried to to it via different sql function but not yet succeeded.

Comment: So did you have a chance to try the answers and see if any of them worked?

Comment: SELECT *,SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(timestamp separator ','),',',1) as time1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(timestamp separator ','),',',-1) as time2,
group_concat(status separator ',') as stat,COUNT(*) as cont FROM order_log ol WHERE (ol.status = 2 OR ol.status = 4)  GROUP BY ol.order_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND stat='2,4'

Comment: I used this query, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Instead of posting your solution as a comment, post it as an answer and then you can mark it as accepted as the question will be marked as resolved (which is helpful to the community).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this query

```
SELECT ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(timestamp separator ','),',',1)  
as time1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(timestamp separator ,'),',',-1)
as time2, group_concat(status separator ',') as stat,COUNT() as cont 
FROM order_log ol WHERE (ol.status = 2 OR ol.status = 4) GROUP BY 
ol.order_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND stat='2,4'
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity, but how is this supposed to tell you the difference between different rows?

Answer (score 0):

Do a self-join, i.e. something like:

```
select t1.*, t2.*, t2.timestamp - t1.timestamp
from tablename t1
  join tablename t2 ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id
where t1.status = 2
  and t2.status = 4
```

I don't know MySQL very well, so the `t2.timestamp - t1.timestamp` part may need adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use a self join (that is, join the table with itself) and use the [timestampdiff function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to get the difference with the granularity you want:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.`time-stamp`, b.`time-stamp`)
FROM `order` a 
JOIN `order` b ON a.order_id = b.order_id
WHERE a.status = 2 
  AND b.status = 4
```

This assumes that there will be only one matching row for each combination of order_id and status. If there can be more than one, you need to select the specific rows to compare somehow.